# ArcGIS Pro not able to find file?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, arcgis-pro

I'm trying to run a script that reads a file in a file geodatabase. I've been running the script in ArcMap 10.5 before without problem, so I think that might have something to do with it.

The script reads a file from a file database and uses in a Con and then save the Con layer as a file.

```
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\\Users\\...\\Output\\NinePoints.gdb" 

rastList = arcpy.ListRasters() 

for raster in rastList: 
    print (raster)
    arcpy.env.workspace
    outCon = Con(raster, 1, "", "VALUE < 100")

    outputReclass = r'C:\Users\...\Output\Area.gdb' #lagres i ninePoints GDB'en
    outputFileName = "area"                             

    outRasterName = '{}{}'.format(raster, outputFileName) 

    outCon.save(os.path.join(outputReclass, outRasterName))
```

The error I get is this one:

```
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000865: Input conditional raster: flate2175reclasscost does not exist.
Failed to execute (Con).
```

---

It actually runs on the first file in the folder, but not on the second, which i find very weird.

---

I added the arcpy.env.workspace to the script and somehow it works now.

Comment: What if you try: outCon = Con(raster(rast), 1, "", "VALUE < 100"). You then also need to change to: for rast in rasterlist

Comment: @BERA Tried that one, but it gives me a String error:   File "<string>", line 9, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: Have you had a look at the rasterlist with: print (rastList)

Comment: @BERA Yes, tried at it all looks correct. I updated the question as it reads the first raster, but not the next one after that.

Comment: Below print(raster) you don't need "arcpy.env.workspace" as you already defined it's location up top. Next I would print outRasterName and see if it exists, it will not over write. You may need env.overwriteOutput = True or see if Exists then delete management.

Comment: @BillChappell What do you mean by the last part? Delete it if it exists? I have overwriteoutput = True

Comment: In testing this your first run creates a file, and for some reason later it may fail, or you tweak the code. So you now run it a second time through. Since the first run worked on the first file, the second run sees the file already there and now fails. I have seen where it's not able to overwrite even with the true settings. So I always use if exists, then delete, so I get a good clean run. see http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/exists.htm for example  Also print outRasterName if it has spaces in the name that maybe an issue.